# Optimizing the code that controls 4-DC Motors using Python Dictionary Comprehension

Tags: python, pwm

I have connected 4 DC motors (each two with L298 H-Bridge IC), now it's time to get them worked using a Python script running on Raspberry Pi B+.
I'll include my code, and I'm totally new that means it's perfect-structured.

> **My aim is:** How can we use Python Dictionaries to illuminate the bunch of code which has a lot of redundancy.

I mean, if anyone can tell how to start, and how to use packing/unpacking arguments to deal with each GPIO indecently.

**NOTE:** I have a seperate file that stores GPIO numbers in a dictionary to provide accessing its contents from any class.

import RPi.GPIO as G
from time import sleep
import config

```
class moving(object):

    """docstring for moving"""
    def __init__(self, duty):
        super(moving, self).__init__()
        self.duty = duty

        G.setmode(G.BOARD)  
        G.setwarnings(False)

        M1F = config.BOARD['DC1_F']
        M1B = config.BOARD['DC1_B']
        M2F = config.BOARD['DC2_F']
        M2B = config.BOARD['DC2_B']
        M3F = config.BOARD['DC3_F']
        M3B = config.BOARD['DC3_B']
        M4F = config.BOARD['DC4_F']
        M4B = config.BOARD['DC4_B']
        # M1F: Enable pin of Motor one Forward 
        G.setup(M1F,G.OUT)
        G.setup(M1B,G.OUT)
        G.setup(M2F,G.OUT)
        G.setup(M2B,G.OUT)
        G.setup(M3F,G.OUT)
        G.setup(M3B,G.OUT)
        G.setup(M4F,G.OUT)
        G.setup(M4B,G.OUT)

        frequency = config.DC_FREQ
        # Frequency is a constant value
        P1F = G.PWM(M1F,frequency)
        P1B = G.PWM(M1B,frequency)
        P2F = G.PWM(M2F,frequency)
        P2B = G.PWM(M2B,frequency)
        P3F = G.PWM(M3F,frequency)
        P3B = G.PWM(M3B,frequency)
        P4F = G.PWM(M4F,frequency)
        P4B = G.PWM(M4B,frequency)

        P1F.start(duty)
        P1B.start(duty)
        P2F.start(duty)
        P2B.start(duty)
        P3F.start(duty)
        P3B.start(duty)
        P4F.start(duty)
        P4B.start(duty)
        # when an object is created, 
        # duty cylce will be inititlised 
        G.cleanup()

    def change_speed(self,new_duty):
        self.duty = new_duty
        pass

    def move(self,direction):
        if directoin == 'F':
            G.output(M1F,1)
            G.output(M2F,1)
            G.output(M3F,1)
            G.output(M4F,1)
            pass
        # and So on for other directions
        pass
```

> Although it may be acceptable that way, I don't feel comfort with that bad way of coding, especially when I decide to expand it with other developments.

**Thanks a lot for every help**